# Removing duplicate strings

Tags: c

I need help in removing duplicate strings. My code is almost there, it outputs the unique strings then crashes, see for yourself. How can I stop this from happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char array[4][4]={"cat","mat","sat","mat"};
    int i, j, k;
    int a=4;

   for (i = 0;i < a; i++) 
   {
      for (j = i + 1; j < 4;) 
      {
         if (strcmp(array[j],array[i])==0)
         {
            for (k = j; k < a; k++) 
            {
               strcpy(array[k],array[k+1]);
            }

            a--;
         } 

         else
         j++;
      }
   }

   for (i = 0; i < a; i++) 
   {
      printf("%s", array[i]);
   }

   return (0);
}
```

Comment: Where does it crash? Are you getting a segfault? Have you tried a debugger like gdb?

Answer (score 2):

If you stepped through your program with a debugger you'd find out that the following is your problem:

```
strcpy(array[k],array[k+1]);
```

When `k == 3` you're attempting to access an element outside the bounds of `array` for the second argument of `strcpy`:

```
array[k+1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not good. When you find a matched string you copy all tail of the array in the new position.

Here is a more simple and clear approach

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N   4

int main(void) 
{
    char s[N][N] = { "cat", "mat", "sat", "mat" };
    int i, j;

    j = 0; /* current osition where a unique string will be placed */
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        int k = 0;
        while ( k < j && strcmp( s[k], s[i] ) != 0 ) k++;

        if ( k == j )
        {
            if ( j != i ) strcpy( s[j], s[i] );
            j++;
        }
    }


    for ( i = 0; i < j; i++ ) printf( "%s ", s[i] );
    puts( "" );

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
cat mat sat
```

Simply copy paste and investigate.:)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use strncmp that strcmp. 
You don't have to iterate through every character of the string as `strncmp` compares strings tills the their end (null terminated strings). From the documentation (man strncmp on unix systems) of the `strncmp`:

> The strncmp() function compares not more than n characters. Because strncmp() is designed for comparing strings rather than binary data, characters that appear after a `\0' character are not compared.

Try this code:

```
char array[4][4]={"cat","mat","sat","mat"};
int i, j;
int a = 4;

 for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {

    bool unique = true;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < a; j++) {
       if (strncmp(array[i], array[j], a) == 0) {
          unique = false;
          break;
       }
    }

    if (unique) {
      printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    }
 }
```